# Is it possible to get "everything" from javax.naming.InitialContext?

Tags: java, jndi

Is it possible to retrieve "everything" (all names) from `javax.naming.InitialContext`? I didn't find any examples or documentation about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the JavaDoc I can see that .list(String name) will return the list of names in the named context and that .getNameInNamespace() will return the name of the InitialContext.  So perhaps you can do:

```
ctx.list(ctx.getNameInNamespace());
```

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as:

`ctx.list("")`